# Why can't I comment on posts with this InstaPy Script?

Tags: python, bots, chatbot, instapy

I have created a python script so I can test the InstaPy module. I have a single problem and I cannot figure out why I cannot comment. I un my script, everything goes to plan, I even like the pictures, but the console output tells me - Not Commented!, which is weird since I have written the session.set_do_comment(enabled=True,percentage=100). Can someone please help me or even explain me why it doesn't work??

```
from instapy import InstaPy

session = InstaPy(username="My_Username", password="My_Pssword",geckodriver_path='geckodriver.exe')
session.login()

session.set_relationship_bounds(min_followers=300,max_followers=10000,min_posts=10)
session.set_quota_supervisor(peak_comments_daily=100,peak_likes_daily=100)
session.like_by_tags(["physics","math","stem","quantum","calculus"], amount=50)
session.set_comments(['Nice','Amazing Post!','Keep up the good work!'])
session.set_do_comment(enabled=True,percentage=100)


session.like_by_tags(["physics","math","stem","quantum","calculus"], amount=50)

session.end()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar issue where it wasn't commenting. I learnt that `session.set_do_comment` must be placed before `session.like_by_tags`. Making that change was the trick.

Even on the official Github repo, this was suggested.